# Justified responsive gallery with Image overlay

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

I have been trying to achieve something for a week now with little progress, I always try to learn everything without help if I can but I am coming to you for help on this one.

I have a decent understanding of HTML and CSS, however some of CSS below is very new to me. Especially the method used to create the justified gallery.

This is what I am trying to achieve - http://thesaxman.com/#gallery

I am trying to replicate it so I can then modify it afterwards, so I have used the inspection tool to get the HTML and CSS.

I have managed to create this - https://jsfiddle.net/807LLbL3/

**HTML**

```
<section id="gallery" class="bh" style="height: 611px;">


<div id="mygallery" class="justified-gallery" style="height: 2398.01027268233px;">

    <div class="single_image" style="width: 321px; height: 256.384663430338px; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;">
        <img src="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Gallery-12.jpg" style="width: 321px; height: 257px;  margin-left: -160.5px; margin-top: -128.5px;">
        <div class="image_overlay text-center">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="view-bigger">
                    <a class="single_image" href="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Gallery-12.jpg" rel="gallery">Grow Icon</a>
                </div>
                <div class="download">
                    <a href="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Gallery-12.jpg">Download ICON</a>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.dangoodofficial.co.uk/&amp;text=Check out @DanGoodeMusic"><span>Tweet Me</span>@DanGoodeMusic</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>

        <div class="single_image" style="width: 385px; height: 256.384663430338px; top: 0px; left: 321px; opacity: 1;">
        <img src="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Gallery1.jpg" style="width: 385px; height: 257px; margin-left: -192.5px; margin-top: -128.5px;">
        <div class="image_overlay text-center">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="view-bigger">
                    <a class="single_image" href="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Gallery1.jpg" rel="gallery">View Bigger</a>
                </div>
                <div class="download">
                    <a href="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Gallery1.jpg">Download</a>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.thesaxman.com/&amp;text=Check out @TheSaxManUK"><span>Click to Tweet</span>“Check out @TheSaxManUK”</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>

        <div class="single_image" style="width: 353px; height: 234.912043507791px; top: 256.384663430338px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;">
        <img src="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Gallery-9.jpg" style="width: 353px; height: 235px; margin-left: -176.5px; margin-top: -117.5px;">
        <div class="image_overlay text-center">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="view-bigger">
                    <a class="single_image" href="http://thesaxman.com/wp-content/themes/thesaxman/library/img/gallery/image19.jpg" rel="gallery">View Bigger</a>
                </div>
                <div class="download">
                    <a href="http://thesaxman.com/wp-content/themes/thesaxman/library/img/gallery/image19.jpg">Download</a>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.thesaxman.com/&amp;text=Check out @TheSaxManUK"><span>Click to Tweet</span>“Check out @TheSaxManUK”</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
        <div class="single_image" style="width: 353px; height: 234.912043507791px; top: 256.384663430338px; left: 353px; opacity: 1;">
        <img src="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Gallery-7.jpg" style="width: 353px; height: 235px; margin-left: -176.5px; margin-top: -117.5px;">
        <div class="image_overlay text-center">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="view-bigger">
                    <a class="single_image" href="http://thesaxman.com/wp-content/themes/thesaxman/library/img/gallery/image20.jpg" rel="gallery">View Bigger</a>
                </div>
                <div class="download">
                    <a href="http://thesaxman.com/wp-content/themes/thesaxman/library/img/gallery/image20.jpg">Download</a>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.thesaxman.com/&amp;text=Check out @TheSaxManUK"><span>Click to Tweet</span>“Check out @TheSaxManUK”</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>




</div>

    </section>
```

**CSS**

```
.gallery img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.gallery img:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

section#gallery {
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1.00)
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay {
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;-
moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;t
ransition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
background-color: rgba(1, 62, 187,0.8); 
opacity:0; position:absolute; 
top:10px; 
left:10px;
right:10px; 
bottom:10px; 
z-index:100; 
display:block; 
border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1.00)}
section#gallery div:hover>.image_overlay {
 opacity:1;
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper {
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position:relative;
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .content {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00);font-size:12px;}
section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .content a { color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00)
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .view-bigger { 
position:absolute; 
top:10px; 
right:10px; 
color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); 
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .view-bigger a {
color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00) !important
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .view-bigger a:after {
content:"\f504";
display:inline-block;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
font:normal 20px/1 'dashicons';
vertical-align:top;
margin-left:5px;
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .download { 
position:absolute; 
bottom:10px; 
left:10px; 
color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); 
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .download a {
color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00) !important
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .download a:after {
content: "\f316";
display: inline-block;
-webkit-font-smoothing: 
antialiased;font: normal 20px/1 'dashicons';
vertical-align: top;    
margin-left:5px;
}
section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .content span { 
display:block; 
font-size:20px; 
font-family: "museo";}



.image_overlay {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: rgba(1, 62, 187,0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
.image_overlay .wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.image_overlay .wrapper .view-bigger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
.image_overlay .wrapper .download {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
.image_overlay .wrapper .content {
  font-family: Righteous;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
  font-size: 22px;
}
.image_overlay .wrapper .content a {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
.image_overlay .wrapper .content span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "museo";
}

@-webkit-keyframes justified-gallery-show-caption-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: .7
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes justified-gallery-show-caption-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: .7
    }
}

@-o-keyframes justified-gallery-show-caption-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: .7
    }
}

@keyframes justified-gallery-show-caption-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: .7
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes justified-gallery-show-entry-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes justified-gallery-show-entry-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@-o-keyframes justified-gallery-show-entry-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes justified-gallery-show-entry-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

.justified-gallery {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden
}

.justified-gallery>a, .justified-gallery>div {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0)
}

.justified-gallery>a>img, .justified-gallery>div>img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0
}
</style>
```

The main issues I am having are:

1. How can make this responsive?
2. How can I get this to span across the full width of the page? I would like to create 3 rows of 4 images spanning the full width of the page. With each row slightly out of line with each other - like the example.
3. In the JSFiddle I included the images have all adjusted automatically 
   Do I need to re-size all the images I want to use accordingly, for them to work more effectively with this method? Would this avoid images been distorted (like the first image in my JSFiddle, which is a little warped)
4. Is there anything else I am missing to make this work?

Thank you,

Dan

Comment: Try using CSS `float`.

Comment: I would use tools like bootstrap or mosaic flow for what you are trying to achieve. 1: http://getbootstrap.com/ 2: https://github.com/sapegin/jquery.mosaicflow

Comment: @Pugazh Where should be adding `float` to get the results?

Comment: @cor Thank you for this, I definitely think this will be useful in the future, but it is not quite what I am after at the moment, although I've been looking for a good masonry gallery for a while.

Comment: If you look at the example website you see that it has a lot of gallery images. the top row of the images always start with: `top:0px`. Your second row starts with `top: 256.384663430338px`. That is why your second row images start at that position. If you want to expand it full page just add more pictures with having `top:0px` as their property

Comment: Here the code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfdh024h/2/)

Comment: @Pierezzz Thank you so much for your help, I just saw your JSFiddle now but I had been working away over the last hour and have managed to create this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/807LLbL3/1/) All that is left to figure out is how to make it responsive, i've tried a few things with no results.

Comment: @DanielJohnson If you want everything to be responsive you have to change every hard coded pixel (e.q 250px) to percentages (e.q 25%). If you do that you the images will resize if you resize your screen

Comment: @Pierezzz Could it not be achieved using jQuery? The example I am borrowing the HTML and CSS uses pixels but is still responsive.

Comment: @DanielJohnson. What do you mean by: "is still responsive?" If you use fixed # of pixel then the only way to achieve responsiveness is by changing the amount of pixel by using jQuery. So that jQuery will check your browser dimension and update the pixels within your inline width and height style.

Comment: @Pierezzz I meant that the example uses fixed pixel widths and heights and is responsive. I think I found the [javascript code](http://thesaxman.com/wp-content/themes/juggernaut/library/inc/plugins/justifiedgallery/jquery.justifiedGallery.min.js?ver=4.1.5%22) used but it I can't seem to get it to work.  I'll keep working on it. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: @DanielJohnson just have a look here: http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/getting-started/ 
That will help you getting started and understand how it works!